# With Ubuntu Linux (10+), how do I connect to remote to my machine from Windows

Tags: remote-desktop, firewall, vnc, realvnc

I tried to to remote into my Ubuntu machine.  I enabled the setting on Ubuntu and that side seems to work.

But I get a connection time out when I use RealVNC on the Windows box.

I believe it is a firewall issue.  I disabled the firewall for that application on Windows but I don't know how to check if the firewall is enabled on the windows machine.

I am on a local network with a router.  Ideally, I would want to block that remote control port at the Internet level/router level but "enable" that port on the Windows box and the Ubuntu box.

How do I check those settings.

Comment: What does 10+ mean? Do you mean you are on version 10.04?

Answer (score 1):

You can check your firewall settings on your ubuntu system with `sudo iptables -L`
By default ubuntu is pretty open so you don't have to manually open ports in the ubuntu firewall for the vnc server to work on the local network.

Windows XP has ports and programs that you can allow in the firewall. You can find the firewall settings under control panel. You should not have to open any ports in windows in order to connect to the linux vnc server.

Routers have a web interface that you can connect to. You can type ipconfig in the windows command prompt and take note of your default gateway. It might be something like 192.168.0.1 or 192.168.1.1. You can then type that address directly into a web browser address bar to get to the router login and settings. Routers are by default not set up to forward any ports... so you probably don't have to worry about people on the Internet having direct access to your ubuntu vnc server.

The default port for vnc is 5900. You can try connecting a vnc client on ubuntu to its self to see if the vnc server is running properly. This can also create a cool effect where your vnc client has the screen of your screen of your screen... inside it.

Answer (score 0):

'netstat -lnt' will tell you if you are listening for VNC. If anything is listening in the range 5900 to 5920 then it is likly VNC.  The last two digit are the VNC port number.  Desktop sharing defaults to asking for confirmation.  If so, you won't get connected from windows until it is accepted on the Ubuntu side.  This should automatically happen after about a minute.

You can also configure XDMCP and vnc4server to allow you to login to a separate desktop from Ubuntu.